# Java logging thread blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, freeze, java.util.logging

I have a problem with java logger as given below. Our tomcat sever will be hang after running around 3 to 4 hours. After tomcat restart it will run again another around 4 hours then again hangs. It is like IVM is hanging.

After I got thread dump it will show as given below code. As my understanding it has issue with logging locking or hard disk read/write operation. Anyone knows is this java 1.6 issue or it will fix in java 7.

I am using java  1.6.0_18 and apache-tomcat-7.0.25.

```
catalina-exec-49" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2fb000f800 nid=0x2a29 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f2f6d4d2000]
 java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
 at it.codegen.logging.CGFileHandler.publish(CGFileHandler.java:684)
 - waiting to lock <0x00007f32dfc56400> (a it.codegen.logging.CGFileHandler)
 at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:458)
 at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:480)
 at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:503)
 at it.codegen.tbx.ResourceManager.startResourceManager(ResourceManager.java:246)
 - locked < 0x00007f32f031ad60> (a it.codegen.tbx.ResourceManager)
 at it.codegen.tbx.ResourceManager.createSession(ResourceManager.java:265)
 at it.codegen.tbx.search.service.TravelBoxSearch.createSessionEx(TravelBoxSearch.java:3667)
 at it.codegen.tbx.search.service.TravelBoxSearch.search(TravelBoxSearch.java:3943)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:246)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:95)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
 - locked < 0x00007f30b6f5f208> (a com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:295)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:515)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:285)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:155)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:189)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:76)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1600)
 - locked < 0x00007f32744cd100> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

//CGFileHandler class publish  method

```
public synchronized void publish( LogRecord record )
{
    int startPos = meter.written;
    if( !isLoggable( record ) )
    {
        return;
    }
    super.publish( record );
    flush();
    int endPos = meter.written;
    setFileNameAndPossistions( startPos, endPos );
    if( limit > 0 && meter.written >= limit )
    {            
        AccessController.doPrivileged( new PrivilegedAction()
        {
            public Object run()
            {
                rotate();
                return null;
            }
        } );
     }
 }

private void setFileNameAndPossistions( int startPos, int endPos )
{
    String additionalKey = ":" + loggerName + ":"+String.valueOf(    
Thread.currentThread().getId() );

    SoapUtility.setContextData( Loggable.FILE_NAME + additionalKey, currentFileName );
    SoapUtility.setContextData( Loggable.START_POS + additionalKey, startPos );
    SoapUtility.setContextData( Loggable.END_POS + additionalKey, endPos );
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using a custom logging handler, CGFileHandler... have you looked at this? It may include synchronized blocks or what-not.

Comment: I check it, CGFileHandler is extend from Handler class and seems like it does not have a issue.

Comment: What exactly is it.codegen.logging.CGFileHandler ?

Comment: CGFileHandler has overwritten the publish() method which is including in the java.util.logging.StreamHandler class. Inside the CGFileHandler it just print the extra log and call again super.publish() method.

Comment: @dngamage Please add the code for CGFileHandler, there has to be something in there...

Comment: ``waiting to lock <0x00007f32dfc56400> (a it.codegen.logging.CGFileHandler)`` indicates that your logger is indeed waiting on a lock. Synchronization in loggers means anything that logs can block anything else that logs. You're better off with a logger that locklessly queues log messages and writes on a background thread.

The question is, what are other threads in the system doing?  Are any of them holding one of the locks you see in that thread dump?

A simple test if CGFileHandler is your problem: Reconfigure logging to do plain old stdout logging, and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I wonder if you have:
public void publish(LogRecord record) {
  super.publish(record);
}
or 

            public synchronized void publish(LogRecord record) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.publish(record);
            }

Comment: Do you use 'public synchronized void publish(LogRecord record){}'? If not, maybe that makes the difference? 

If your CGFileHandler class is not using 'synchronized' method and is up-casted to StreamHandler, then the JVM may recognize 'handler.publish()' as synchronized (which is not) and go wild. 

I'm not sure, just thinking loud.

Comment: Please see above error message. I have append publish method into that

Answer (score 3):

You have a classic deadlock situation. Thread `catalina-exec-49` holds 3 locks (on a `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel`, a `com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber` and a `it.codegen.tbx.ResourceManager`) and it's waiting to acquire a 4th (to enter the synchronized `publish` method on a `it.codegen.logging.CGFileHandler`.

The problem is that another thread has already acquired the lock on the `CGFileHandler` (maybe by entering the `publish` method, or another synchronized method on the same instance), and is waiting to acquire one of the locks that `catalina-exec-49` holds. Neither thread can advance, leading to deadlock.

Without seeing detailed code and stack dumps, etc., I can't give you specific advice, but generally you should:

- limit the extent of synchronized blocks to the bare minimum
- avoid calling outside a method holding a lock
- structure your code so that locks are always acquired in a specific order